# Django 'File' object has no attribute '_size' on Change Form in Admin

Tags: python, django

I have this model with a clean method to validate upload of mp3 files in django admin (note the audio_file field):

```
class Cancion(models.Model):


    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100
                              ,verbose_name=_("nombre"))
    audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to="audio"
                                  , verbose_name=_("audio"))
    album =  models.ManyToManyField("music_manager.Album"
                                    ,through="music_manager.CancionAlbum"
                                    ,through_fields=('cancion', 'album')
                                    ,verbose_name=_("canciones_albums")
                                    ,related_name="cancione_albums")
    reproducciones = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("reproducciones")
                                         ,default=0)

    playlist =  models.ManyToManyField("music_manager.Playlist"
                                    ,through="music_manager.CancionPlaylist"
                                    ,through_fields=('cancion', 'playlist')
                                    ,verbose_name=_("canciones_playlist")
                                    ,related_name="cancione_playlist")

    class Meta:


        verbose_name_plural= "Canciones"
        verbose_name = "Cancion"
    # Override the __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
    def __unicode__(self):


        return self.nombre

    def clean(self):
         file = self.audio_file.file
         print("Archivo: "+str(file))
         if file:
             if file._size > 20*1024*1024:
                   raise ValidationError(_("El archivo de audio es demasiado grande ( > 20mb )"))
             if not file.content_type in ["audio/mp3"]:
                   raise ValidationError(_("El archvivo no es MP3"))
             if not os.path.splitext(file.name)[1] in [".mp3",]:
                   raise ValidationError(_("El archivo no posee la extension apropiada"))
             # Here we need to now to read the file and see if it's actually
             # a valid audio file. I don't know what the best library is to
             # to do this

             return file
         else:
             raise ValidationError("Couldn't read uploaded file")
```

The clean function works well when creating a new model object. However, when changing an attribute of the object on the admin change form I get:

```
'File' object has no attribute '_size'
```

Can anyone tell me what I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`_size` is an internal Django attribute that it uses to cache the file size - it is not always set (e.g., when editing an existing object in the admin). You should not be accessing it directly.

Instead try [`file.size`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File.size).

Comment: Thanks that removed the error. But now I get the same thing with the content_type attribute. Is there a subsitute for this one too?

Comment: The `content_type` attribute is only present on [uploaded files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.content_type). Once they are saved, there is no such attribute. You need to add [custom validation to the admin form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin) to do this on submission rather than every time the object is edited.

Comment: Note the warning in the documentation that checking the `content_type` does not guarantee that the file is actually an MP3 file.

Comment: Thanks. Yes i guess I'll have to use an external library to check if it is mp3.